# how to create openCL test that run on multiple devices

Tags: opencl

I’d like to have questions about how to create openCL test that run on multiple devices 
Assume I want to create an openCL program that calculates the expression A*B + C*D,and  this is what I think of

1. Create 3 kernels , one for A*B, one for C*D, and other for M + N (A*B+C*D)
2. Create a host code that do 3 tasks in parallel and each task to run in different device but I dont know how to assign specific device for a single task

Please help me
Thank you

Comment: where did you stop? did you select platform and devices then select queues but couldn't assign tasks to those devices?

Comment: which version of opencl? What kind of devices? What kind of work distribution?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL is, all things considered, a pretty explicit API. It asks you to specify a specific device when creating a context, and it asks you to specify a specific context when creating a queue. So in the most literal terms, accomplishing your task is as simple as

```
//This is going to be pseudocode; I'm not going to look up the literal syntax for this stuff
//It is going to closely resemble how you'd write this code in C++, though
std::vector<_type> perform_tasks(cl_device_id ab_device, cl_device_id cd_device, cl_device_id n_m_device) {
    cl_context ab_context = clCreateContext(ab_device);
    cl_context cd_context = clCreateContext(cd_device);
    cl_context n_m_context = clCreateContext(n_m_device);
    cl_command_queue ab_queue = clCreateQueue(ab_context, ab_device);
    cl_command_queue cd_queue = clCreateQueue(cd_context, cd_device);
    cl_command_queue n_m_queue = clCreateQueue(n_m_context, n_m_device);
    cl_kernel ab_kernel = get_ab_kernel(ab_context, ab_device);
    cl_kernel cd_kernel = get_ab_kernel(cd_context, cd_device);
    cl_kernel n_m_kernel = get_ab_kernel(n_m_context, n_m_device);
    set_args_for_ab(ab_kernel);
    set_args_for_cd(cd_kernel);
    set_args_for_n_m(n_m_kernel);
    cl_event events[2];
    clEnqueueKernel(ab_queue, ab_kernel, &events[0]);
    clEnqueueKernel(cd_queue, cd_kernel, &events[1]);
    //Here, I'm assuming that the n_m kernel depends on the results of ab and cd, and thus 
    //must be sequenced afterwards.
    clWaitForEvents(2, events);
    copy_ab_and_cd_data_into_n_m_buffers();
    cl_event n_m_event;
    clEnqueueKernel(n_m_queue, n_m_kernel, &n_m_event);
    clWaitForEvents(1, &n_m_event);
    return copy_n_m_data_to_host();
}
```

But there's a bigger question that needs to be addressed, which seems to have gone unconsidered by your question: ***Why?***

What kind of performance gains are you expecting to gain from this kind of logic, rather than simply writing something like the following, executed on a single device?

```
kernel void ab_cd(global _type * a, global _type * b, global _type * c, global _type * d, global _type * output) {
    long id = get_global_id(0);
    output[id] = a[id] * b[id] + c[id] * d[id];
}
```

With the kind of program logic you're proposing, you're going to incur unavoidable overhead from simply trying to transfer data between different devices (which would occur inside `copy_ab_and_cd_data_into_n_m_buffers()` in the pseudocode I described). If you're committed to using multiple devices for this kind of program, it's still simpler (and probably more performant!) to write something like this:

```
//Again; using pseudocode. Again, gonna look like C++ code.
cl_event perform_tasks(cl_device_id device, cl_context * context, cl_command_queue * queue, cl_kernel * kernel) {
    *context = clCreateContext(device);
    *queue = clCreateQueue(context, device);
    *kernel = get_kernel();
    cl_event event;
    clEnqueueKernel(queue, kernel, &event);
    return event;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<cl_device_id> device_ids = get_device_ids();
    std::vector<_type> results;
    std::vector<cl_context> contexts(device_ids.size());
    std::vector<cl_command_queue> queues(device_ids.size());
    std::vector<cl_kernel> kernels(device_ids.size());
    std::vector<cl_event> events;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < device_ids.size(); i++) {
        events.emplace_back(perform_tasks(device_ids[i], &contexts[i], &queues[i], &kernels[i]));
    }
    clWaitForEvents(events.size(), events.data());
    for(cl_command_queue const& queue : queues) {
        std::vector<_type> result = read_results_from_queue(queue);
        results.insert(results.end(), result.begin(), result.end());
    }
    //results now contains the results of all executions
    return 0;
}
```

Unless you're working with FPGAs, or dealing with a particularly exotic workload, where it's absolutely essential to have different devices doing different work, you're probably just creating more work for yourself than you need to.

Comment: Thank you Xirema, I am working on a openCL test that run on multiple FPGA devices so it is really causing me headcahe

Comment: @tpham1002002 Wait, you actually *are* dealing with FPGA's?? Huh. Well, as I mentioned, the first code I provided will deal with that model. Bear in mind though that my original assertion still applies: there are very few scenarios where it makes sense to split a single calculation across multiple devices, especially if the sub-components of that calculation are similar between devices.